# dispatching an action from componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, action, reducers

I have to fetch some data just after the component is mounted in react.i am using componentDidMount method and inside that i want to dispatch an action but when i am calling *popular()* (see code) it does nothing and if i do *dispatch(popular())* it showns error that dispatch and popula not defined
**Please note that i have not used mapDispatchtoProps**. What can i do to fetch the data ? Any help would be appreciated.

**/action.js**

```
export function popular(){
    return dispatch=>{
        return fetch(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=<key>&language=en-US&page=1`)
                .then(data=>data.json())
                .then(data=>{
                        console.log("fetched",data);
                        dispatch({
                        type:"popular",
                        data:data.results,
                        page:data.page,
                        total_pages:data.total_pages,
                        total_results:data.total_results
                        })
     
                    })
    }
}
```

**/App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {Header} from './header.js';
import {Searchbar} from './searchbar.js';
import {Thumbnails}from './Thumbnails.js';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {Select} from './select.js';
import { Pagination } from './pagination.js';
import {Filterbar} from './filterbar.js';
import { popular } from '../redux/action.js';

class App extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount(){
        console.log("heloo");
        popular();
           
        }

    render(){
        return (
            <>
                <Header /> 
                <Select {...this.props}/>
                <Filterbar/>
                <Searchbar {...this.props}/> 
                <Thumbnails {...this.props}/>
                <Pagination {...this.props}/>       
            </>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {
        state:state
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To dispatch the `popular` action you need provide `redux-thunk` middleware to redux and pass `popular` action through `mapDispatchToProps`.

Here an example:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.getPopular();           
}

....

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
 return { getPopular: () => dispatch(popular()) };
}
```

Read more about that in the [thunk docs](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk).
Also I recommend you refresh [basics of redux](https://redux.js.org/basics/basic-tutorial). Just because you have some confuse. Naming and usage tell me about that.

Comment: i have used thunk ...but not mapDispatchtoProps.is it neccesary to use mapDispatchtoProps.I have dispatch some other actions without it ..but they were not in lifecycle method.

Comment: `popular` returns a function that expect `dispatch` as argument. Thunk will provide it to an async actions. I will update answer to write an example.

Comment: What if i want to call an action creator with event as a parameter

Comment: Just pass it as argument in `popular(someArg1, someArg2) { ... }`. Usage in mapDispatchToProps: `(arg1, arg2) => dispatch(popular(arg1, arg2));`